# Looking for the most common abbreviation to indicate the end of a working day

Tags: word-choice, abbreviations

I'm looking for an abbreviation to indicate that I finished work for the day.
Example usage: "I'm going home, its ... for me".

I found some examples on the internet, but I'm wondering what's most common to use.

- EOB (end of business)
- EOD (end of day)
- COB (close of business)
- ...

[Wikipedia (End of Day)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_day) uses COB, but Googling didn't give much info about its usage.

EDIT: Context on where I would use it is writing (e-mail). I communicate with different teams in different time zones and it would be a handy way to let people know they don't need to expect a quick response from somebody because that person has already left the office (gone home).

Comment: BOC - beer o'clock ... for the light hearted.

Comment: "X has finished for the day" would be the usual expression in my experience. You need to allow for the fact that even in one office, not everyone finishes at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience, "COB" is a commonly used acronym to express delivery of a project or task by the end of business on a certain day. *EDIT: You would only ever write this, not say it out loud to a colleague.*

> "I will make sure to send you that spreadsheet by COB Thursday."

I have rarely encountered the construction "end of **_**" in that context. I usually see it as "EOM" or "EOY" in financial or management reports.

If you're looking for something to use in everyday language with your co-workers, mplungjan's "It's curtains for me" or a phrase like "I'm throwing in the towel for today" is appropriate. Saying "It's COB for me" would sound weird.

Answer (score 2):

I've voted for @THEAO answer because I agree that COB is the most common business term for the end of the day.

However, I'd also like to offer the simple ***"home time"***.

> I'll pick up that task tomorrow; it's home time for me.

Answer (score 0):

I work in the tech sector, where it's common practice for some to work well past the typical 5 or 6pm closing time of many industries. In my sector I've often encountered COB to indicate a deliverable due at the end of the business day (~5:00 / 6:00pm). Whereas EOD will often indicate a deliverable due whenever the contributor stops working, typically into the evening.